For JCrypt LFSR Stream Cipher Utilization, is it Possible to Have Registers of n>15?
I'm performing theory and technical research on reversing the logic output of an old, decaying and fragile arcade board IC that utilizes LFSRs in order to generate multiple randomized star-field effect patterns on the game screen, dependent largely on a combination of V/H-sync signals from the video controller, and other matrix-control lines being asserted High or Low. So I'm trying to utilize JCrypt in order to single out max-length, 16-bit keystream polynomials to test against all valid/possible seed values, and then compare those outputs to reference output from the original chip for each respective seed and max-length polynomial configuration found for n=16.
JCrypt says that a maximum of 25 registers can be displayed, but when I attempt to increment to my desired n of 16, it appears that the register/tap count maxes out at 15. Is this by design? A hard limitation? Can the program be modified from source and recompiled to allow for n=16(+?) registers being simulated through the LFSR stream cipher?
